# ffmpeg HLS Multiple Audio Renditions

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, segment

How can I convert an mp4 video file having inside 3 audio tracks (english, german and french) to an HLS playlist having :

- one videofile.m3u8 and its corresponding segmentsfile.ts
- one audiofile-english.m3u8 and its corresponding segmentsfile.aac
- one audiofile-german.m3u8 and its corresponding segmentsfile.aac
- one audiofile-french.m3u8 and its corresponding segmentsfile.aac
- one masterfile.m3u8 like that :

```
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="medium",NAME="#1 Fre",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="fre",URI="medium/planete_interdite_500_h264_240p_audio1_fre.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="medium",NAME="#2 Eng",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="eng",URI="medium/planete_interdite_500_h264_240p_audio2_eng.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="medium",NAME="#3 Fre",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="de",URI="medium/planete_interdite_500_h264_240p_audio1_de.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3274000, CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=854x480,AUDIO="medium"
medium/planete_interdite_2080_q264_480p.m3u8
```

Comment: I can't tell if you intended the "#" to be there or not, but I adjusted the rendered output to not use headings.  Please remove the "#" if they were unintended.

Comment: this link help you : https://kipalog.com/posts/FFMPEG-HLS-STREAM-MULTIPLE-AUDIO-SUBTITLES

Answer (score -1):

You can use ffmpeg for firstly convert only hls video with flags -an -sn, than converts hls audio streams with flags -vn -sn, and finally make playlist with some scripts